# get specific part from url

Tags: regex

my window.location is "F:/html5/home.html", from my location i need to get the file name like this "home.html", to do this, how to i use the regular expression command?

any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it

```
[^/]+$
```

It matches the substring of non-forward-slash characters towards the end of the string.

```
var s = "F:/html5/home.html";
//forwards slashes must be escaped in JavaScript regex as it is the delimiter
alert(s.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're flexible about not using regular expressions, I would do this:

```
var pathArr = new Array();
pathArr = window.location.split("/");
var file = pathArr[pathArr.length - 1];
```

Comment: You don't need to make that first array.